# Date Difference in todays date and purchase date between 60 to 90 days in MY SQL

Tags: mysql

I want to execute SQL query where Date Difference between Today's date and Purchase date should be between 60 to 90 days of Range. How to get it ?

Comment: Please at least add some sample table data to your question.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from your_table
where purchase_date >= curdate() - interval 90 day
  and purchase_date <= curdate() - interval 60 day
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_name where  abs(datediff(curdate(),table_name.purchase_date)) <= 90 && abs(datediff(curdate(),table_name.purchase_date)) >= 60;
```

Comment: That can not make use of any indexes and is slo on big tables

Comment: What do you mean indexes?

Comment: Indexes on columns which make queries fast. It is a very important part of DB design. You should look it up

Comment: That depends entirely upon if he has indexed the date columns or not. Anyway thanks for the insight,